# What's the difference between these two marking types?

Tags: datasheet

On the datasheet for LTC3526L, it says the LTC3526L and LTC3526LB have two different part markings, LCSS and LCST, respectively. What does that mean? Below it says For more information on lead free part marking go to: http://www.linear.com/leadfree/

That link leads me to their material declarations page. When I search for the LTC3526L and LTC3526LB the material declaration is exactly the same for the two.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The part markings are the text stamped or engraved on the physical ICs.  There are two different part markings here because the LTC3526L and LTC3526LB are two functionally different parts.

The difference between those parts appears to be in how they handle light loads.  From the bullet points on the first page of the datasheet:

[image]

And from further along in the datasheet, under the heading "Burst Mode Operation":

> The LTC3526L will enter Burst Mode operation at light load
> current and return to fixed frequency PWM mode when the
> loadincreases.

and

> The LTC3526LB features continuous PWM operation at
> 1MHz. At very light loads, the LTC3526LB will exhibit
> pulse-skip operation.

Note that in most places the datasheet refers to "The LTC3526L/LTC3526LB", whereas in these places it refers to only "The LTC3526L" or "The LTC3526LB".  There may be other differences, but on a cursory reading of the datasheet this appears to be the most important difference if not the only one.

Comment: From my read of the datasheet I agree that this is the only functional difference between the two, but so you're saying that if I were to receive both of these ICs, one would have the marking LCSS on it and the other would have the marking LCST on it?

Comment: yes, precisely.  The different top marks are there so that the two functionally different ICs can be distinguished, before or after assembly onto a PCB